# Load more rows from database on click without page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to have my loop stop at 5 rows by default, but when the button is clicked it would load more. Are there any simple solutions for this? I don't want the page to refresh either.

My code below:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thequery)))  {
    echo $row['title'];
    $count+=1;
    if($count%5==0){
        break 1;
    }
}
?>
<span onClick="loadmore_somehow">Load More</span>
```

Comment: you need to use javascript and AJAX

Comment: you can take a look at jQuery DataTables http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Answer (score 2):

An AJAX call would do that. Using Javascript (and preferably a library like jQuery) you would make a call to your script and get more rows, pass them back, and then use Javascript to draw the rows. This does not reload the page.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know more about Javascript Ajax, It will help you do update,retrieve  the content without refreshing page.

Check out this tutorial http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1350